# Как проверить слово в python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Использую pyTelegramBotAPI. Если первое слово !add, то выполнять определённое действие, Т.е

```
     elif message.text[0,1,2,3,4] == '!add':
        add_message(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.id)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Ваш запрос добавлен в базу данных!\nВ скорем времени 
        мы вам ответим!')
```

Но по индексу проверить не получается

Comment: Такое вообще работает message.text[0,1,2,3,4]  ?)

Comment: @AlioshcaZ, можно реализовать класс, для которого такое будет работать. Для строк такая конструкция работать не будет.

Answer (score 3):

Будем считать, что `message.text` - строка.

**1 вариант:** вырезать 4 первых символа и сравнить с нужными

```
elif message.text[:4] == '!add':
```

Выкинет исключение, если строка короче 4 символов. Также условие будет срабатывать на более длинные команды, начинающиеся на `!add` - какой-нибудь `!addmeplease`, например. Можно в этом случае проверять не 4 символа, а 5 символов с пробелом:

```
elif message.text[:5] == '!add ':
```

Но это не отменяет необходимость проверки длины строки.

Еще один минус этого способа - можно забыть исправить размер слайса, в итоге условие всегда будет ложным, например:

```
elif message.text[:4] == '!add ':
```

- тут будут сравниваться строки разной длины - 4 и 5 элементов, это всегда `False`.

---

**2 вариант:** проверять начало сообщения с помощью метода `startswith`

```
elif message.text.startswith('!add '):
```

Этот метод сам уже учитывает длину исходной строки (если строка слишком короткая - метод просто вернет False)

---

**3 вариант:** разбить строку по пробелам, взять первый элемент. В данном случае удобно использовать метод `partition`:

```
elif message.text.partition(' ')[0] = '!add':
```

Отличие от метода `split`:

- `split` разбивает строку по разделителю, возвращает список частей. В случае пустой строки - это будет пустой список, соответственно получение первой части вызовет исключение
- `partition` разделяет строку по первому разделителю. Для любой строки возвращает три элемента: первая часть, разделитель, остальная часть. Если разделитель не найден - то вся исходная строка и две пустых строки. Если исходная строка пустая, то будет три пустых строки. Поэтому можно спокойно проверять первую часть на равенство нужному параметру.